# is there a way to fix this PropType error, it says I am passing fromData as String instead of object

Tags: reactjs, frontend, form-data, react-proptypes

This is an error I am getting from my webpage console

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `formData` of type `string` supplied to `FirstSection`, expected `object`.
at FirstSection (http://localhost:5173/src/Components/applySections/FirstSection.jsx?t=1708303938624:14:25)
at ApplicationForm (http://localhost:5173/src/Containers/ApplicationForm.jsx?t
at Routes (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom)

I am beginner at web-dev and I am getting the above error when I use formData in my FirstSection.jsx. So I am making an application form that is divided into different sections. I have implemented these different sections as different files e.g. firstSection.jsx, secondSection.jsx, thirdSection.jsx; in addition to this there is a parent component ApplicationForm.jsx where I combine all these sections to complete my application form. I have implemented these sections using formData so that it is easily rendered from the parent component.

below is my ApplicationForm.jsx which is the parent component:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import FirstSection from '../Components/applySections/FirstSection';
import SecondSection from '../Components/applySections/SecondSection';
import ThirdSection from '../Components/applySections/ThirdSection';
import FourthSection from '../Components/applySections/FourthSection';
import FifthSection from '../Components/applySections/FifthSection';
import SixthSection from '../Components/applySections/SixthSection';
import SeventhSection from '../Components/applySections/SeventhSection';
import './ApplicationForm.css';

const ApplicationForm = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        FirstSection: {},
        SecondSection: {},
        ThirdSection: {},
        FourthSection: {},
        FifthSection: {},
        SixthSection: {},
        SeventhSection: {},
    });

    const [showReview, setShowReview] = useState(false);

    const handleFormChange = (section, data) => {
        setFormData((prevData) => ({
          ...prevData,
          [section]: data,
        }));
    };

    const handleReview = () => {
        setShowReview(true);
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try{
            await fetch('localhost:5000/applications', {
                method: 'POST', 
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify(formData),
            })
            console.log('Submitting Form');
            alert("Your application has been submitted successfully!");
        } catch(err){
            console.log(err);
            alert("An error occurred while submitting your application. Please try again later.");
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className='application-form-container'>
            <FirstSection formData={formData.FirstSection} onFormChange={(data) => handleFormChange("FirstSection", data)} />
            <SecondSection formData={formData.SecondSection} onFormChange={(data) => handleFormChange("SecondSection", data)} />
            <ThirdSection formData={formData.ThirdSection} onFormChange={(data) => handleFormChange("ThirdSection", data)} />
            <FourthSection formData={formData.FourthSection} onFormChange={(data) => handleFormChange("FourthSection", data)} />
            <FifthSection formData={formData.FifthSection} onFormChange={(data) => handleFormChange("FifthSection", data)} />
            <SixthSection formData={formData.SixthSection} onFormChange={(data) => handleFormChange("SixthSection", data)} />
            <SeventhSection formData={formData.SeventhSection} onFormChange={(data) => handleFormChange("SeventhSection", data)} />

            <button onClick={handleReview}>Review</button>
            <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>

            {showReview && (
                <div className="review-modal">
                    <h2>Review Your Information</h2>
                    {/* Display a summary of entered information */}
                    {/* You can format and display the information as needed */}
                    <pre>{JSON.stringify(formData, null, 2)}</pre>
                    <button onClick={() => setShowReview(false)}>Close</button>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );

    
};

export default ApplicationForm;
```

and this is my FirstSection.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './FirstSection.css'

const FirstSection = ({ formData = {}, onFormChange }) => {
  const updateFormData = (field, value) => {
    onFormChange(field, value);
  };
```

so the question is what does the above error mean and how can I fix it?

I have tried writing inline code that makes sure the formData rendered from the parent component is indeed an object but the error still remains.

Answer (score -1):

Update the `FirstSection` component to handle cases where `formData` is not an object. One way to do this is to check if `formData` is an object before using it. If it's not an object, you can set it to an empty object. Here's an updated version of your `FirstSection` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './FirstSection.css';

const FirstSection = ({ formData, onFormChange }) => {
  const updateFormData = (field, value) => {
    onFormChange(field, value);
  };

  // Check if formData is an object, otherwise set it to an empty object
  if (typeof formData !== 'object' || formData === null) {
    formData = {};
  }

  // Rest of your component code
};

FirstSection.propTypes = {
  formData: PropTypes.object,
  onFormChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default FirstSection;
```

**Explanation:**
Adding the check for `typeof formData !== 'object' || formData === null` and setting `formData` to an empty object if it's not an object, you should be able to resolve the warning.

This ensures that `formData` is always treated as an object, even if it's not provided correctly from the parent component.

---

PS: If this answers your question, remember to mark it as answered and/or upvote if you liked it! :-) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers